# On the size of maximal clique and intersection number of graphs

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

Let $G$ be a finite simple undirected graph. Let $G^c$ be the complement graph of $G$ (
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_graph) .

Assume that every maximal (w.r.t. set inclusion ) clique of $G^c$ has the same size and denote this common size of a maximal clique by $\omega (G^c)$.

Let $\Omega (G)$ be the intersection number of $G$ (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_number_(graph_theory) .

Then is it true that $\omega(G^c)-1\le \Omega (G)$ ?

Comment: Yes, it is true.

Comment: @Misha Lavrov: do you mind adding a proof to your claim and posting it as an answer ? Thanks

Comment: Yes, I don't want to do your homework if you haven't shown any effort.

Comment: @Misha Lavrov: well, it's not really a homework ... the left hand side of the inequality is the Krull dimension of the Stanley-Reisner ring of the clique complex of $G^c$ which is the same as the edge ring of $G$ , and I'm trying to get a nontrivial bound for the dimension of the edge ring ... if you realise(or understand) what I mean, you'll probably change your mind ...

Comment: I recommend including such details in the question to begin with, they motivate it and make it a bit more interesting to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's true; what's more, the condition on maximal cliques of $G^c$, and the $-1$ in the inequality, are both unnecessary.

If $\omega(G^c) = k$, then there is a set of vertices $\{v_1, v_2, \dots, v_k\}$ forming a clique in $G^c$, and so none of the edges $v_iv_j$ exist in $G$. Therefore in any cover of $G$ by cliques, we are forced to put each vertex $v_i$ in its own clique, and so at least $k$ cliques are needed. This means that $\Omega(G) \ge k$.